# Embedding Kibana dashes and security issues

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to create an web app and embed Kibana dashboards. I can export their URLs and embed them in my web application but how can I secure these URLs? Take into account that I don't want to use the x-pack plugin.

Comment: What about build login screen to your application?

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume you mean dashboards with dashes?
2. While Kibana is mainly for the internal use, you could create a readonly user for anonymous access for your dashboards, though you will need some security plugin like X-Pack to enforce it.

Generally you should create a custom visualization with D3.js or whatever you want. Exposing Kibana is not really ideal in most cases.